# autotest, growl, and Ruby on Rails 3 Tutorial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, autotest, growl

I'm running through Ruby on Rails 3 tutorial, and have been having difficulties with the autotest.  Many of them have been handled, but the solutions only seem to bring up subsequent issues.

I am currently on page 96 of the tutorial (if it helps).  Every prior works, but when inputing

$ autotest

This is what I get back:

```
/Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby -rrubygems -S /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial2/gems/rspec-core-2.6.4/bin/rspec --tty '/Users/user/rails_projects/sample_app/spec/controllers/pages_controller_spec.rb'

Finished in 0.07129 seconds

2 examples, 0 failures

2011-12-06 16:22:58.293 growlnotify-1.1.5[60480:903] could not find local GrowlApplicationBridgePathway, falling back to NSDNC
```

This is pretty close to what is supposed to come out, except the last line:

```
2011-12-06 16:22:58.293 growlnotify-1.1.5[60480:903] could not find local GrowlApplicationBridgePathway, falling back to NSDNC
```

Seems to be an issue with Growl, but can't seem to fix it.  Have reinstalled growl, reinstalled rspec, to no avail.

My Gemfile is as follows

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.0.9'

gem 'sqlite3-ruby', '1.3.2', :require => 'sqlite3'

group :development do
    gem 'rspec-rails', '2.6.1'
end

group :test do
    gem 'rspec', '2.6.0'
    gem 'webrat', '0.7.1'
end
```

Any help or direction would be much appreciated.

Comment: Figured it out.  Growl wasn't starting automatically, so needed to open in Mac's System preferences.

Comment: Lucapette, I tried to.  But apparantly I don't have enough cred on the site to answer my own questions. Alas...